# Java selenium 3.6.0 Cannot set Profile

Tags: java, selenium

So I downloaded the new version of selenium (3.6.0)and been having issues getting the profiles for firefox to work. Originally I had it working with 3.5.3, but I am at a loss now.. I have tried everything I can think of and on these forums with no avail!

I am trying to load a user profile "Selenium" - I have tried

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
 FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("SELENIUM");
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
```

and this

```
  ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile profile = listProfiles.getProfile("Selenium");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

I've also tried setting the Firefox profile to be default, so that it just opens that one, but I now see that selenium creates an anonymous profile each instance. 
This was working before, but I see it is now depreciated. and I cannot figure out how to use FirefoxOptions to open the the profile. If you could point me in the right direction that be great! I've tried the java example from the release updates but it does not work correctly..

I have searched every link on google, for many things related, and simply cannot find an approach that will work. Everything keeps pointing me back to that the way I am doing it now is depreciated..
Thanks

Comment: please show full of code you have tried and the error log you got

Comment: Like i said it was working, but then i Updated to 3.6.0. I am simply trying to launch a browser that is using the selenium profile. Nothing more nothing less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using latest version of selenium,I would suggest you to use DesiredCapabilities in org.openqu.selenium.remote package and your jdk compliance level should be 1.8.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path_to_geckodriver.exe");
    File file = new File(path_to_your_firefox_profile);
    DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(file);
    dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Refer this blog for more details.
http://himanshuupadhyay.blogspot.com/2014/01/firefox-webdriver-profile-desired.html

Let me know this works out for you.

Comment: Funny enough I was just looking at something that was mentioning this. And I managed to get it loading the plugins I needed. Which was just as effective as loading the profile I created..
     
The path that I would be setting for the firefox profile is the directory? AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\912mk1r8.Selenium ? Correct? I ask because while this does launch the browser it is still using the wrong profile?

Comment: Yes,the path points to the directory.This directory gets cretaed whenever you create a new custom firefox profile.

Comment: Okay, well i manged to get it working because of this. But now its not finding elements.. Any ideas why that could be happening?

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='inputEmailHandle']")).sendKeys(username);//FIND USERNAME FIELD AND TYPE USERNAME.

Comment: It should work if the element exists in the page.Are you sure that xpath identifies element in your page?and check case-sensitivity of id value.

Comment: Yes, using firebug I see - #inputEmailHandle 

so I did - but its not working just causes an exception
driver.findElement(By.css("inputEmailHandle")).sendKeys(username);//FIND USERNAME FIELD AND TYPE USERNAME.

Comment: This might be due to case when your selenium code tries to access the element too fast, before it appears on the page.Try introducing wait before xpath statement.Also,make sure that page is visible area of the page so that xpath can find it when your code executes

Comment: Tested that too, the element is on the page before it even tries to execute I have verified that.

Answer (score 1):

All answers totally ignore the "setProfile" question.
Here's the answer, how to implement "setProfile":

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile myProfile = allProfiles.getProfile("Selenium"); 
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.setProfile(myProfile);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

The probable reason for this is the [changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG#L6) for 3.6.0 stating -

- All `Option` classes now extend `MutableCapbilities`
  `new RemoteWebDriver(new ChromeOptions());`
- Deprecating constructors that don't take strongly-typed `Options`.

Comment: Would you be able to point me in the direction of somewhere that would have an example of how to go about using this approach? I have seen this on the changelog, but the example they had was giving compile errors.

Comment: @Kabone Though currently I am not very actively working on selenium, yet would give it a try to pull some corrective measures with the updated version.

Comment: Thanks I will look into this

Answer (score 0):

I am using selenium WebDriver 3.7.1 I am writing a code for firefox profile it will work on firefox version 57.0.2.

Step 1 : Create Firefox profile by type command "firebox.exe -p" create profile name as "myprofile".
Step 2 : follow the following code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","P:\\javaapi\\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
FirefoxProfile FF = new FirefoxProfile(new File("C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\es610sjr.myprofile")); // path to firefox profile
dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, FF);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Comment: I eventually moved away from geckdriver and started using chrome driver. No issues anymore :) but yea that looks like it would work:)